# Out of memory Exception at WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf

Our server is running in production environment, but after running for few days, out of memory exception occurs at WCF call.

```
Line 36007:    GlobalUnhandledException: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Line 36063:    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
Line 36063:    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
Line 36064:    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
Line 36065:    at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

We have try to give the maximum array size in configuration. Binding configuration of WCF at server side.

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" sendTimeout="00:00:35" transactionFlow="true"  >
      <reliableSession enabled="true" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Is there is memory leak issue happening at WCF connection calls?

Service behaviour:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
                 ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false)]
```

Is there something I missed during configuration, what are steps to rectify or identify this out of memory exception any help on this matter is appreciated.

UPDATE:
Operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your configuration is the issue.

This is what your configuration means:

`InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall` - Start a new service instance for each call made to the service.

`ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` - Allow multiple threads to start within the service instance

`ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete = false` - Do not release the service instance once the call is complete.

**EDIT:**

Based on your `OperationContract` for the method, I would specify the `OperationBehaviour` for the method and configure the Transaction completion behaviour according to your needs.

[MSDN for ReleaseInstanceOnTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.releaseserviceinstanceontransactioncomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) - has a good example of how `OperationBehaviour` should be configured to automatically complete the Transaction once the underlying operation has completed.

The underlying cause of your `OutOfMemoryException` is highly likely to be not completing Transactions and thus not causing the WCF `ServiceInstance` to be shutdown and garbage collected.

Comment: I have a operation contract with transactionFlow is allowed and according to msdn doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.releaseserviceinstanceontransactioncomplete(v=vs.110).aspx  
you must explicitly set ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete to false if there is an operation with OperationBehaviorAttribute.TransactionScopeRequired set to true

Comment: It would help if you posted that information. Without the appropriate `OperationContract` method definitions to support that in your question then using that config would result in a memory leak as you're not killing the service instance after each call. I would still start with those methods to ensure service instances are being shutdown correctly.

Comment: I updated the question, I didn't get the last line, service instances are being shutdown correctly, how to achieve this? Do you mean I should not use transactionflowoption.Allowed.

Comment: Please see edit. With TransactionFlow you need to ensure the Transaction is completed in order for the ServiceInstance to be garbage collected.

Comment: Seems logical to me, but said so it will be very hard to find which transaction is not completing. I will try to generate dump for more analysis.
Or do you have some better idea to find it.

Comment: What could work would be to implement IDisposable on your service classes and log a message when Dispose is called. The offending call will not result in a call to Dispose() once Transaction is completed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will implement this. :)